how to disable the suggestion coming everywhere in my Laravel controller routes model
The Suggestion URI Controller Action how to prevent them to show
i Tried To Disable Inline Suggestion But not working Anyway to fix i Tried To off Inline Suggestion I am using
Laravel Extra Intellisense
laravel intellisense
so any way to fix that
The Suggestion URI Controller Action how to prevent them to show

Everyone wants this, and you need to turn it off. Okayy. 1. Disable the plugin. 2. There is a separate setting for it.(maybe a file or in setting menu)

disable autocompletes like LaravelExtraIntellisense.disableAuth and LaravelExtraIntellisense.disableBlade, if that don't work disable the hole extension..
